# Issues with logistic regression using `glmnet` package

Tags: r, regression, binomial-distribution, glmnet

I'm trying to use the `glmnet` package to build a logistic regression model, but I keep getting sensitivity and specificity of 1.000.

My data contains two factor predictors: `family` and `gender` as well as a numerical predictor `result` and uses a response variable `autism`.

Can anyone see any glaring issues with the code? I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

```
# assemble data for training and testing
train.factors <- model.matrix(autism ~ gender + family, data=asd_train)[,-1]
train.x <- as.matrix(data.frame(asd_train$result, train.factors))
colnames(train.x) <- c('result', 'gender', 'family')

test.factors <- model.matrix(autism ~  gender + family, data=asd_test)[,-1]
test.x <- as.matrix(data.frame(asd_test$result, test.factors))
colnames(test.x) <- c('result', 'gender', 'family')

# logistic regression
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(train.x, as.factor(asd_train$autism), 
                    family="binomial", 
                    type.measure="class",
                    nfolds=10, 
                    nlambda=100)

# test using testing dataset
predict_validation <- predict(cv.fit, newx=test.x, s=c(cv.fit$lambda.min), type="class")

# create a confusion matrix
cm <- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predict_validation), as.factor(asd_test$autism))
```